# Codeigniter Session library error

Tags: php, macos, codeigniter, session, xampp

i'm receiving this strange error, does anyone knows about it?

```
Severity: Notice  --> unserialize() [<a href='function.unserialize'>function.unserialize</a>]: Error at offset 0 of 286 bytes /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/login/system/libraries/Session.php 723
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means that probably something went wrong with the string of user_data inside your session-table. It could be that the value of user_data was editted and this can make a serialized string "corrupt".

You should check the documentation on php.net about serialization. About how this process works. http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

Comment: anyway i'm not using session table

Comment: What definitly is strange is that this rule points at: "* @return string" The comment above the protected _unserialize function (CI 2.1.3). But is assume that CI session will store data in a cookie by serializing it. If this cookie is changed by some other code than this could make this data-string corrupt and it is trying to unserialize it but it won't be able to do so.

Comment: yep, definitely i fixed all updating from ci 2.0 to latest version really strange that, also i updated my apache server now everythings ok :/